# shapefile mask for georaster in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, raster, shapefile

I am trying to make a mask for a georaster (netCDN file) using a shp file. This is similar to what is described in this thread ([How to limit the raster processing extent using a spatial mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000272/how-to-limit-the-raster-processing-extent-using-a-spatial-mask)), but since my georaster is not an image I do not have an R variable, so the solution presented there does not work for me.

I first load my shapefile into MATLAB:
S1 = shaperead('Export_Output_3.shp');

The data has a Lambert Conformal Conical projection and the units is meters.

Then I load the netCDF file and extract the first slice of data. I get a matrixx with one valu for each cell. It also has a Lambert Conformal Conic projection with the same parameter values, but the data is in “degrees north” and “degrees east”.

So how can I put this data together? I tried the utm2deg function for converting the units of the shapefile from meters to degrees, but I do not know the UTM zone, so I got stuck with that.

I think that I first need to have both datasets in the same units and then to convert the shapefile into a matrix with the same resolution as the netCDF. I am unable to perform any of these steps.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I know who to display geoencoded Lambert Conical Charts in general but don't know your specific problem.